# External DVD writer, strange behavior

Tags: dvd

I have an issue with my external dvd writer (Samsung SE208GB). When I insert an audio CD in it, it seems that the system recognizes the cd, it creates a "Audio CD" un the launcher, waits a few seconds and creates another one, then another one, and it doesn't seem to stop. Impossible for me to rip music with Rhythmbox.
What can I do about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with another disk?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing no matter what i put inside...